# iOS firebase getInitialMessage not working Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I installed firebase notification package in my Flutter project and setup the necessary settings for sending data.

Everything works fine on android, when the app is completely closed, when I send a parameter via firebase, the page I want opens, but on the ios part, when I click on the notification, it does not catch the click and the page I want does not open.

I would be very happy if you could help me where is the main point I should pay attention to for the ios part.

Main.dart

```
  initialMessage = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage();
  if (initialMessage != null) {
    if (initialMessage!.data['type'] == 'notification') {
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 4));
      navigatorKey.currentState?.pushNamed(
          '/notification'); // navigate to login, with null-aware check

    }
  }
```

pushNotificationService.dart

```
class PushNotificationService {

  Future<void> setupInteractedMessage() async {
    await Firebase.initializeApp();

    RemoteMessage? initialMessage =
        await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage();
 
    if (initialMessage != null &&
        initialMessage.data['type'] == 'notification') {
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 6));
      navigatorKey.currentState?.pushNamed(
          '/notification'); // navigate to login, with null-aware check

    }
// Also handle any interaction when the app is in the background via a
    // Stream listener
    // This function is called when the app is in the background and user clicks on the notification
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      // Get.toNamed(NOTIFICATIOINS_ROUTE);
      print(message.toMap().toString());
      print(message.data['type'].toString());
      if (message.data['type'] == 'notification') {
        navigatorKey.currentState?.pushNamed('/notification');
      }
    });
    await enableIOSNotifications();
    await registerNotificationListeners();
  }

  registerNotificationListeners() async {
    AndroidNotificationChannel channel = androidNotificationChannel();
    final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
        FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    var androidSettings =
        const AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
    var iOSSettings = const IOSInitializationSettings(
      requestSoundPermission: false,
      requestBadgePermission: false,
      requestAlertPermission: false,
    );
    var initSetttings =
        InitializationSettings(android: androidSettings, iOS: iOSSettings);
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initSetttings,
        onSelectNotification: (message) async {
      // This function handles the click in the notification when the app is in foreground
      // Get.toNamed(NOTIFICATIOINS_ROUTE);
    });
// onMessage is called when the app is in foreground and a notification is received
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage? message) {
      // Get.find<HomeController>().getNotificationsNumber();
      print(message!.data['type'].toString());
      print(message.toMap().toString());
      if (message.data['type'] == 'notification') {
        navigatorKey.currentState?.pushNamed('/notification');
      }
      RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
      AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;
// If `onMessage` is triggered with a notification, construct our own
      // local notification to show to users using the created channel.
      if (notification != null && android != null) {
        flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
          notification.hashCode,
          notification.title,
          notification.body,
          NotificationDetails(
            android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
              channel.id,
              channel.name,
              icon: android.smallIcon,
              playSound: true,
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    });
  }

  enableIOSNotifications() async {
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance
        .setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
      alert: true, // Required to display a heads up notification
      badge: true,
      sound: true,
    );
  }

  androidNotificationChannel() => const AndroidNotificationChannel(
        'high_importance_channel', // id
        'High Importance Notifications', // title
        importance: Importance.max,
      );
}
```

info.plist background modules

```
UIBackgroundModes
        fetch
        processing
        remote-notification
```

Comment: When you tap notifications & recieve data check notification map will different for Android & iOS platform. So you have to write platform specific code for that. So debug and check notification map part for iOS. So just check log for  initialMessage.data  Map for iOS.

Comment: i am seeing the same behavior so i am going to make an issue on Github regarding this.